# 2 delegates on UITableViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates, uitableview

I have a Controller class and in its header file looks as below:

```
@interface ClassA : UITableViewController<Class1Delegate, Class2Delegate>
```

Can I 2 delegates on UITableViewController? If I do this, I get an error saying "Incomplete Implementation" on the implementation of the controller class.

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like you did not implement all @required methods of mentioned protocols

Comment: They're actually called protocols.

Comment: Go through that Objective-C tutorial again. These are not necessarly 'delegates', rather **protocols.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement all required methods for protocols that you are realise.
In this example all required methods of

- Class1Delegate
- Class2Delegate

Go to Class1Delegate, Class2Delegate and see methods that goes after **@required** directive.

Also see [UITabelViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this.  In your case the compiler is just complaining that you have not implemented all the methods for both of the protocols.